# gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid

Tags: gtk, gtk3, cache, icon-themes

i'm working on some editing icon theme and when i want to update the icon cache i got this error :

```
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /usr/share/icons/test-ico
```

so i made a double check to `theme.index` file and compared the files name and directories in it and tried to add `-f` , `-t` and `-q` to my command :

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -q -t -f  /usr/share/icons/test-ico
```

but i still got the same error and warning message.

so how can i find the error cause to fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check two things :

1. The name of icons directories in `theme.index` file like (apps/24x24, places/128x128 ... etc) if they listed in index file and dose not exist in icons directory ( or vis versa)
2. The names of icons images if they have a white spaces or some thing like this

As you said, you made a double check for `theme.index` file and dirs, so you need to check the images names.
for me I use this command inside the icon dir :

```
ls -a -R * > ~/outfile.txt
```

to list all images names, after that I replace the white spaces with `(@)` symbol  using my text editor to find and fix the images names.

Comment: It's work for me! i found some icons with white spaces and after changing these icons names and update the icons  cache  the command working without any error and got :

`gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.`

thank you so much