# Trash Bin icons missing. How to get them back?

Tags: nautilus, icons, gnome-shell, trash

In Ubuntu 18.04, when my Trash Folder is empty, Nautilus shows this:

[image: Nautilus]

The default Trash bin icon seems to have disappeared. Not only that, but the Trash bin icon in the shortcut menu on the left of Nautilus also appeared to have disappeared. How do I revert them back?

Remark: I did not perform any desktop configuration procedure but Ubuntu recently did do an `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

**Update:**

I ran `sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*` and nothing happened. My icon issue still persisted. The themes that I used was in my local folder. There were errors:

```
$ sudo update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons/*
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for ~/.local/share/icons/Cupertino-Catalina-iCons-master
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for ~/.local/share/icons/Cupertino-iCons-master
```

My system is using `Cupertino-Catalina-iCons-master` which has a failure warning. Does this mean the icon theme is no longer workable and I either have to use newer versions of that or use another icon theme? Or can I fix the issue myself?

Comment: can you change your icon theme to some other themes n verify?

Comment: also check this post https://askubuntu.com/q/722708/739431

Comment: @PRATAP I can see the Trash Bin icon when I used different `Icons Theme` in `Tweaks`.  This would mean something happened to the trash bin icon in the theme that I was using. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Your above comment confirms that the problem is with the Icon Theme. manually fixing it is not a good idea. you can raise the issue with the theme author about this.. have you tried the link update cache.. command?

Comment: @PRATAP According to the theme's folder, I could see the svg for empty Trash Bin. Not sure why they aren't appearing. Will try the link update cache command next.

Comment: @PRATAP The theme that I am using seems to have had a failure warning. See my update in my question. What should I do next?

Comment: can you go through this post https://askubuntu.com/q/1080257/739431?

Comment: @PRATAP I tried removing white space in the file names as mentioned in the link you had provided. I found two: `gnome-control-center datetime.png` and `gnome-control-center sound.png` and replaced the whitespace with `@` symbol. The warning from `sudo update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons/*`  no longer appears. yet, the missing empty trashcan icon problem persisted. I installed the latest version of `Cupertino-Catalina` icon theme and found that it did not have the missing trashcan icon issue but it did have the same whitespace in the same two filenames. Using the latest version now.

Comment: I think you can ignore white spaces editing as you dont have problem with latest version of the theme..